# SQL: Input Prompt in an Access passthru query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a working query in Access to linked SQL Server tables that I pass user input to using

```
WHERE (RIGHT(dbo.qryrptWhereUsed.ITEM, 9)=[INPUT_PROMPT:])
```

I would like to continue using Access to store similar simple queries that require user input but want to do this via a passthru query directly to the SQL Server db thus eliminating the mirrored tables in Access.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: you don't, directly.  Create your pass-through query with SQL Server syntax, then apply the runtime parameter with an Access query built on top of it.  Or, if you really want their limit embedded in the pass-through SQL, you'll need to use VBA to modify your pass-through query's SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
  Dim strPrompt     As String

  strPrompt = InputBox("Enter where used >")

  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPass")
     .SQL = "select * from dbo.qryWhereUsed where ITEM = '" & strPrompt & "'"
     .Execute
  End With
```

If you running a report, then just go:

```
  Dim strPrompt     As String

  strPrompt = InputBox("Enter where used >")

  With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPass")
     .SQL = "select * from dbo.qryWhereUsed where ITEM = '" & strPrompt & "'"
  End With

  DoCmd.OpenReport "myreport", acViewPreview
```